# Bind subdomain to IP

Tags: ip, port, ubuntu-11.04

I have Ubuntu 11.04 Natty and I'm using the bind9 service.
I have it configured like this:

```
$TTL                    86400

example.com.         IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. root.example.com. (2012111201 10800 3600 604800 86400)
example.com.         IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
example.com.         IN      NS      ns2.example.com.

ns1.example.com.     IN      A       55.55.44.44
ns2.example.com.     IN      A       44.44.55.55
example.com.         IN      A       55.55.44.44

*.example.com.       IN      CNAME   example.com.
```

Now, all of my subdomains point to my main domain's IP, the first NS (55.55.44.44)

What I'm trying to do is have a subdomain point to another IP if the port is changed.
For example:

test.example.com on port 80 would point to 55.55.44.44 and test.example.com on port 25565 would point to 33.33.33.33

**Further explanation:**
I host a website on test.example.com on port 80, on the same server where the bind9 service is. But if you would save test.example.com in Minecraft it has to point to 33.33.33.33:25565.

So:

```
test.example.com:80       ->    55.55.44.44:80
test.example.com:25565    ->    33.33.33.33:25565
```

Is this possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. DNS only resolves to the IP address level.

The closest you could get would be the configure the machine the DNS resolves to to perform port forwarding.

Comment: how would i go about doing a port forwarding from test.example.com:25565 to 33.33.33.33:25565

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=set+up+port+forwarding+on+ubuntu+-ssh

Comment: nvm, i have figured it out with socat

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. DNS has no knowledge of ports.